# jQuery hide show slide hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some difficulties in one of the jQ features I've implemented. The problem is that slide animation is hiding/showing multiple times for some of the attempts. I want it to be showing only once after hovering an element. 
All is working fine but sometimes is fading few times when mouse is hovering element, so if you move a mouse but you're still hover it shouldn't happened. I want it to fade every time you hover but it should animate only once per hover but sometimes is fading few extra times per one hover. Try to move a mouse between title and the content when hovering.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.latest_module').hover(function(){

    var front = $(this).children('.cb-article-meta');
    var back = $(this).children('.cb-article-meta-hover');
    var backh2 = $(this).children('.cb-article-meta-hover').children('h2');
    var backp = $(this).children('.cb-article-meta-hover').children('p');
    var img = $(this).children('.cb-grid-img');
    $(front).css('display','none');
    $(back).css('display','block');
    $(img).addClass('latest_module_hover');
    $(backh2).hide().show("slide", { direction: 'right' },800).css('padding','0 20px');
    $(backp).hide().show("slide", { direction: 'left' }, 800).css('padding','0 20px');

},function(){

    var front = $(this).children('.cb-article-meta');
    var back = $(this).children('.cb-article-meta-hover');
    var img = $(this).children('.cb-grid-img');
    $(front).css('display','block');
    $(back).css('display','none');
    $(img).removeClass('latest_module_hover');

});
```

});

[Testing on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bgsx23nc/10/)

Thanks,

Comment: your fiddle is not working.

Comment: Sorry you have to remove %20http// from redirected link, some wrong conversion happened

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is that you only want hover to run the first time you can just unbind it when it enters with this `$(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave')`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.latest_module').hover(function(){
        $(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave')
        ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bgsx23nc/12/

**EDIT:**
or as suggested by [Guruprasad Rao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2065039/guruprasad-rao) only on leave

```
...
 $(img).removeClass('latest_module_hover');
         $(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave')

    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/bgsx23nc/13/

Comment: Good solution but I suggest to keep `$(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave')` on `mouseleave` as OP might want to hide the same once shown! +1 though!

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate on your comment? Didn't quite get what you meant.

Comment: Like see this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/bgsx23nc/13/)**, Once `mouseout` that particular hiding event must take place as he has written one for `mouseleave`! So keeping your line of code in second part! Hope its clear now..

Comment: I edited the message to include both solutions, let OP decide what he wants. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: sorry, that's not what I'm looking for, I've just added extra explanation. All is working fine on my example but sometimes is fading more then once when you hovering, eg if you move a mouse, it's difficult to reproduce but sometimes happens

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `class` to the sliding `element` and then from next time check if it has `class` already and if yes don't do anything like one below:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/bgsx23nc/11/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.latest_module').hover(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('hoverDone')) //check if it has class and if no then
        {
            $(this).addClass('hoverDone'); //add class once hover done
            var front = $(this).children('.cb-article-meta');
            var back = $(this).children('.cb-article-meta-hover');
            var backh2 = $(this).children('.cb-article-meta-hover').children('h2');
            var backp = $(this).children('.cb-article-meta-hover').children('p');
            var img = $(this).children('.cb-grid-img');
            $(front).css('display','none');
            $(back).css('display','block');
            $(img).addClass('latest_module_hover');
            $(backh2).hide().show("slide", { direction: 'right' },800).css('padding','0 20px');
            $(backp).hide().show("slide", { direction: 'left' }, 800).css('padding','0 20px');
        }
    },function(){
        var front = $(this).children('.cb-article-meta');
        var back = $(this).children('.cb-article-meta-hover');
        var img = $(this).children('.cb-grid-img');
        $(front).css('display','block');
        $(back).css('display','none');
        $(img).removeClass('latest_module_hover');
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry, that's not what I'm looking for, I've just added extra explanation. All is working fine on my example but sometimes is fading more then once when you hovering, eg if you move a mouse, it's difficult to reproduce but sometimes happens

Comment: @Adam Its very hard to reproduce your problem buddy!!

Comment: Yeah, I know, please try to move a mouse between News 4 title and the content below, try to hover few times and move it in this area

Comment: yep!! I tried but I definitely feel that somewhere mouse focus is going out and this stuffs dont misbehave!! still not sure in your case!!